# forward declaration for objective-c interfaces

Tags: objective-c, interface, forward-declaration

How do I forward declare this object:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <AVAudioSessionDelegate>
{

}

@end
```

in objective c

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a forward declaration of an ObjC type:

```
@class MyClass;
```

And this is a forward declaration of an ObjC protocol:

```
@protocol AVAudioSessionDelegate;
```

---

For those of you who are curious why this is useful: Forward declarations can be used to significantly reduce your dependencies and significantly reduce your build times because it allows you to avoid `#import`ing headers and/or entire frameworks (which then `#import` other frameworks). When forward declarations are not used, many unnecessary headers are visible to other parts of your program -- changing one header can cause many files to be recompiled, and the compilation and link times will go up. Because ObjC types are always dealt with as pointers (at our abstraction level), the forward declaration is sufficient in most cases. You can then declare your ivars in your `@implementation` or class continuation and the `#import` can then go in the `*.m` file. Another reason is to avoid circular dependencies.

Comment: This does not actually answer how I should forwardly declare @interface objects. An example using what I gave would be helpful.

Comment: excuse me, Your answer DID solve my issue I just did't fully anderstand what you meant. @interface object are also predeclared with     @ class MyClass; I was expecting something more like @ interface Myclass;. Sorry for that. THANKS

Comment: Phenomenal answer.  You wouldn't think to use `@class`, since Objective-C uses keywords `@interface`/`@implementation`.  I google searched for "@interface @implementation forward declaration" to find this.